# SUMIF where criteria matches a value inside a call containing comma separated values?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet where one column is "PROJECT ID" and another is "COST". Typically each row only includes a single PROJECT ID, but sometimes multiple projects are listed, separated by commas.

```
PROD ID          COST
CB100            $100
CB101            $200
CB100, CB101     $50
```

I am trying to SUMIF the cost for each project, so the SUMIF criteria would total $150 for project CB100 and $250 for CB101.

Is this possible via formulas? Or maybe Pivot Tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SUMIF function supports wildcards, so the formula would look like this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*CB101*",B:B)
```